# Generic typing python

Tags: python, typing

Недавно увидел, что можно для Generic использовать ParamSpec -> class Base(Generic[T, P]), а для чего это надо непонятно в документации?

Comment: Начнём с того, что узнаем так в чём же заключается ваш вопрос.

Comment: @DaYa Как это можно использовать ParamSpec? Вообще смысл этого?
[int [float, str]]

Comment: Да. Там плохо раскрыт смысл использования ParamSpec для дженериков. А тот пример, что там есть, ничего не поясняет, ведь с TypeVar будет то же самое. Но вам следует подробнее описать суть проблемы. А то сходу не понять.

Comment: В примере так то в классе с дженериком есть и Callable поле - вот для него.